# VB Script Creating variable on the fly returned Error Automation type not supported

Tags: variables, vbscript, runtime

I have list of variables in an include files which is looks like:

```
var_1 = "string"
var_2 = "string"
```

on the main file i need variable created on the fly so i do

```
' somewhere i have the num variable
Execute("new_var = var_"&int(num))
```

Exactly on the execute line i got this error

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a01ca'
Variable uses an Automation type not supported in VBScript
```

Any idea guys?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use arrays to acheive this sort of thing:-

```
ReDim var(1)

var(0) = "String"
var(1) = "String"

''# somewhere I have the num variable
new_var = var(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it, the error come up when i use casting type to the num variable

```
Execute("new_var = var_"&int(num))
```

but

```
Execute("new_var = var_"&num)
```

works, thanks

Comment: It may work but its very very ugly and quite slow, why are you doing this instead of using an array?

Comment: because i dont want to make another query to database just to get a single value, list variable rendered by service, so i need to include the rendered file and get the value on the fly